# Working with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following design:

```
MainActivity
     |                      /->AddingActivity
     |-------Fragment One---\->DialogFragment
     |-------Fragment Two    
     |-------Fragment Three
     |-------Fragment Four
```

MainActivity hold the fragments. Fragment One can start AddingActivity (with context from MainActivity) which adding data to DB and then all fragments should refresh with the new data. DialogFrgment started from FragmentOne is adding some data to SharedPreference and only the FragmentOne should know about this. MainActivity impliments DialogFragment.OnTimeSetListener (The dialog picks time) and then in MainActivity onTimeSet triggers function in Fragment One to refresh the data.

What I did for now is overridden OnCreate in each fragment and the fragment refreshes when it returns back to view. But the app is bit **laggy** because each fragment refreshes its neighbors and I get some fragment refreshed **twice**.

Can you please advise me about the correct approach to this design, and how can I make the app work more smooth and correct.

Comment: What are using for database . I suggest Use `Room` for DB to reflect changes in real time . In this way you do not need to reload fragments only data will change .

Comment: I am using SQLite. I am not familiar with Room. But still you not have to refresh view for reading from the DB?

Comment: `Room` with `LiveData` provide a  `Observer` to listen for changes in database. If it difficult to upgrade to ROOM for you . Then in simplest wayyou can use startActivityForResult () to open `AddingActivity` and setresult back to activity and specify whether to reload data or not .

Comment: I will try this solution

Comment: Quick solution: AddingActivity returns RESULT_OK when finishing, MainActivity implements onActivityResult, then calls function of each Fragment. That function of each Fragment should refresh fragment view, update data etc...

Comment: If you are using viewPager for fragments then calling viewPager.notifyDataSetChanged(); in onResume() method of MainActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of `MainActivity` implementing `DialogFragment.OnTimeSetListener` and then notifying `FragmentOne` seems kind of strange.

This is how I would do it:

`FragmentOne` **and** `MainActivity` implement `DialogFragment.OnTimeSetListener` as well. However, only `FragmentOne` should be notified from the *dialog fragment* when the time changes, as it is the one responsible for setting the time. Then when this happens, `FragmentOne` should notify the activity:

```
@Override
public void onTimeSet(Time time) {
    ((DialogFragment.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity().onTimeSet(time);
}
```

When `MainActivity` receives the *time set* event, it must update the other fragments, but if possible, it should not re-create them. Just let them know the time was set so that they can update their views accordingly. Each fragment will update itself depending on what it is displaying, etc.

---

In case the problem persists and you still have lag, check if you do too much work on the main thread, e.g. a long-running *for-loop* and try to execute it on another thread.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `LocalBroadcastManager` to refresh the the fragments , that way you can have the control to which fragment to refresh and not all at the same time , and you should also check if the DB is causing the lag.

Here is an example how to use `LocalBroadcastManager` you should implement it on your own way.

https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-how-to-send-and-receive-local.html